# What is the general form of an inner products in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, products

I am studying Linear Algebra and my professor proposed an exercise:

Let $\mathbb{R^n}$ a vector space, $v=(v_1,...,v_n)$ and $u=(u_1,...,u_n)$, then there is a general form for Inner Product between $u$ and $v$?

My attempt:

I know that the inner product is bilinear, comutative, $\langle u , u \rangle \geq 0 $  and  $\langle u,u \rangle = 0 \iff u=0.$
So I think that the general form of Inner Product is:

$ \langle u,v \rangle = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_jv_ju_j,\hspace{0.5cm}$ where $\alpha_j \geq0, \forall j=1,...,n.$

But, how I arrive in this expression? and every Inner Product has this form?

Comment: So you know that $u = \sum u_i e_i$ and $v = \sum v_j e_j$, where $\{ e_i \}$ is the standard basis. Now what's $\langle u, v \rangle$?

Comment: this is a notation for Inner product, like $v^t \cdot u$

Comment: Oh, I know. I'm asking you, now that you've written $u$ and $v$ in terms of the standard basis, what will be their inner product $\langle u, v \rangle$, for any arbitrary inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$? Try writing it, and conclude something from it.

Comment: ok, $\langle u,v \rangle = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n v_j u_j$, because $\langle e_i,e_j \rangle = 0$ for $i \neq j, $ or $1$ if $i=j.$ , it's over?

Comment: No, $\langle e_i, e_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ for a particular inner product. In general it could be something else, since we're considering an arbitrary inner product. Nevertheless it cannot be _anything at all_, since it's an inner product, which has to satisfy the properties you mentioned. So use that to draw your conclusions

Comment: @Joãonani I think we can have cross-terms also in an inner product, no?